# ask about this error:Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#

This is my first time.Hi,I'm working on a SQL project and write a C# program for retrieve it.But I can't solve this error. please help me.Thanks.here my code:

```
 private void Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {   

        var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        db.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO Students VALUES ({105},{ali},{askari},  {ma@yahoo.com},{091345})",

        new object[] { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox6.Text });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = db.Students;

 }
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below it is a best practise to use SQL Parameters to avoid SQL Injection exploits. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18339247/1193596) for an example on how they can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

`INSERT INTO Students VALUES ({105},{ali},{askari},  {ma@yahoo.com},{091345}` to

`"INSERT INTO Students VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})"`

This is a simple string format issue where the arguments need to be in that format.

Answer (score 1):

[ExecuteCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx) takes a params[] object and a format string. It looks like this is what you're attempting to use.

In which case you have it wrong and it should be:

```
db.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO Students VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})", 
                              105, "ali", "askari", "ma@yahoo.com", 091345);
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter numbering is position based:

```
//db.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO Students VALUES ({105},{ali},{askari},  {ma@yahoo.com},{091345})",
 db.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO Students VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4})",
   new object[] { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox6.Text });
```

It is unclear what you want the `{105},{ali},{askari}, ...` values waere meant to be.

You may also need quotes around your string values, like:

```
 db.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO Students VALUES ({0}, \"{1}\", \"{2}\", \"{3}\", \"{4}\")",
```